# Filter Replication set by username

Tags: .net, winforms, replication, filtering

I have a Merge Replication setup between a central server and 200 clients.  The vast majority of the clients do not need all 5000 client records.  Only the 50 or so that are assigned to them.  How would I go about applying a Filter based on who's logged in?

Should I create a NEW DB that maps user names to Client Records and go down that path?

Any better ideas or pitfalls?  How is everyone handle this kind of ***per user*** filtering?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this use either `HOST_NAME()` or `SUSER_SNAME()` to filter by either the *host name* or *current user* respectively.

Use the below when building the filter statement in the **Publication Properties**.

`i.e. salesrep = SUSER_SNAME()`

See **SQL Docs** for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I know that MS Dynamics CRM use view on the server with a huge select to look at who has permission to see what. When someone query that view it only returns what he can see.

Maybe you could do something like that.